# Nicest way to 301 Redirect traffic when changing permalink settings

Tags: permalinks, redirect

If I change my permalink structure, is there is a nice way to handle when people/bots go to the old structure?

I presume I can add use .htaccess and write a rule to redirect based on a 301 but is it possible in my case?

I currently have site.com/%year%/%month%/%day%/%postname% and I will just want site.com/%category%/%postname%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dean's Permalink Migration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalinks-migration-plugin-for-wordpress/) has always worked for me. Install it before you change your permalinks.

Comment: afaik Dean's thing is no longer available / working.

Answer (score 0):

For people, you can try [Smart 404](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-404/).

Answer (score 0):

You can typically perform the 301/302 redirect in the functions.php file of your theme.

Here is one of many references you can find - http://perishablepress.com/permanent-301-redirect-via-php-or-htaccess/

Comment: Seems like that reference only covers static urls. The question is clearly in regards to dynamic urls.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two plugins for this: either [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) - a good way to manage your changed urls / permalinks, and [404 Redirected](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/404-redirection/), which is good for logging and manually fixing permalink errors.